# Javascript fetch api payload not delivered

Tags: javascript, php, json, post, fetch

```
console.log("data ", data); // returns an object in JSON format {propertyName: propertyValue}
dataString = JSON.stringify(dataString); //correctly stringified json

let response = await fetch('updateRecevingEntry.php', 
                {
                method:'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, 
                body: dataString
            }).then(response=>response.json());
```

however I get back an undefined index on the php side.

where the php is:

```
$matkey = $_POST['materialKey'];
```

returns

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: materialKey in <b>path/updateRecevingEntry.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

for all the data... none of it is getting caught.

so why is the _POST['propertyName'] not catching the stringData from the body?

I've tried a few variations, such as sending the data instead of the string data messing with the header, but I can't seem to figure out how to send the payload such that _POST['propertyName'] catches the data in the body.

I was using $.ajax from jquery before, and it was working: but I'm in the process of refactoring that out.

the Fetch api is new to me. where am I going wrong. I also don't want to parse a json object on the php side.

after reading one of the answers, I got it to work in one case,
but

```
        let response = await fetch('updateRecevingEntry.php', 
                {
                method:'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, 
                body: sendData  
            }).then(response=>response.json());
```

and the php

```
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
var_dump($postData);
```

just returns a big fat NULL.

Edit two: turns out it just needs to actually be encoded via JSON.stringify(sendData). Since the. It works as expected.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` most likely it's json_encoded, in which case you'd need to decode it first

Comment: copy, that's what I was avoiding, anyway to send it correctly such that I DON'T parse a json object on the php side of things?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is where you're encoding it. Try sending it without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I've noticed is that you're not using the right variable (you're using `stringData` instead of `dataString`):

```
dataString = JSON.stringify(dataString); //correctly stringified json

let response = await fetch('updateRecevingEntry.php', {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, 
    body: dataString    
}).then(response=>response.json());
```

Though you shouldn't need to stringify it as you're sending it with json headers.

---

Additionally, have you tried instead of `$_POST`, using `php://input`?

From [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

So you would use it like so:

```
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$matkey = $postData['materialKey'];
```

This reads the body of the POST request as a JSON string then converts it to a PHP array.

Comment: aye, the typo was from posting to here, I'm going to fix that now.

Comment: that works. and while it's using json_decode, it will do.
but how to you write a fetch request such that you can send an object and have it populate _POST['propertyName'] correctly?

Comment: In order for $_POST to work, the data needs to be sent as `FormData` and not as `JSON`, but I don't see why you would want $_POST when php://input is giving you the same result. If the answer worked, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer :)